# Ubuntu user autologin openbox

Tags: users, openbox, auto-login

I have created a new user and set the autologin to on, but it runs into openbox after restarting. I tried to exit openbox but it is unresponsive after I click exit and I disabled the autologin for user from terminal.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: My version is 17.10